# Cannot debug or attach debug C code (linux) from VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a C code on Ubuntu.
All code is written in one file (main.c). The 'tasks.json' and 'launch.json' are generated by default.
However, I cannot 'Start Debugging' or 'Run without Debugging' from VS Code. The breakpoint is NOT stopped at.

I actually debug and attach debug well with VSCode many times, but this time is very very weird.

My tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger.",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent",
                "clear": true,
                "showReuseMessage": false
              }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

My launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

My main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

When running without debug or with debug, the terminal always output:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file <

Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -g /home/user/checkVscode/main.c -o /home/user/checkVscode/main
Build finished successfully.
```

I notice that the executable file doesn't run with VSCode. Because if it runs, the "Hello, World!" will be displayed in the VSCode integrated Terminal.

Running the executable alone (from Ubuntu terminal) is totally fine (the "Hello, World!" is displayed).

I also tried attach debug (putting a sleep(10) before the printf line) and configure launch.json to use with attach debug properly. But same, the breakpoint is never stopped at.

Please help me!

Thanks so much

Comment: Are you able to debug or attach from the command line? -- What are the errors or reactions of VSCode?

Comment: I can debug and attach debug from gdb (command line) with this executable (and code of course). But cannot debug or attach debug in VS code

Comment: The VSCode doesn't show any error. The executable seem to NOT be executed (that's why the breakpoint is never stopped at). But why it is not executed when clicking button 'Start debugging' ?. Here is log of VS code terminal when debugging:


> Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file <

Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -g /home/user/checkVscode/main.c -o /home/user/checkVscode/main
Build finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error as above. However, when I mark debug in the main function and debug some other lines in the program. Then, i ran "start debuging (F5)" then debug worked for me.

Helpful solution for those who have the same problem as me.